# How can I convert PropertyInfo[] to Dictionary<string,string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reflection, dictionary, html.dropdownlistfor

Actually I need the properties of my class to be displayed in a mvc dropdown. I'm using reflection to get those things. But now my problem is to get them as key value pairs to display them in dropdownlist.

I am using the below code...

```
public static Dictionary<string,string> SetProperties()
    {
        Type T = Type.GetType("Entity.Data.Contact");
        PropertyInfo[] resultcontactproperties = T.GetProperties();

        ViewContactModel viewobj = new ViewContactModel();
        viewobj.properties = resultcontactproperties;
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        return dic;
    }
```

So how to convert them to dictionary to get them in the below dropdown...?

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.properties, new SelectList(Entity.Data.ContactManager.SetProperties(),"",""), "Select a Property")

Well this is my ViewContactModel

public class ViewContactModel
    {

        public List<Entity.Data.Contact> Contacts;
        public int NoOfContacts { get; set; }
        public Paging pagingmodel { get; set; }
        public PropertyInfo[] properties { get; set; }
    }

In the view I'm using this model
```

Comment: Well what object are you trying to fetch the values from? You've got a new `ViewContactModel`, but presumably that doesn't actually contain a contact. There's no information here about *which* contact to fetch values from...

Comment: what is the key and what is the value you want?

Comment: I don't want a particular contact.. I am looking only for the properties in the class Entity.Data.Contact. It has properties like Name,Mobile,Email,State,city,Country etc ..I want those proprties in the dropdown..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use a Dictionary and assuming that the Name and the Value of each dropdown item is the property name itself, you could use something along the following lines:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetProperties<T>(params string[] propNames)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] resultcontactproperties  = null;
        if(propNames.Length > 0)
        {
            resultcontactproperties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => propNames.Contains(p.Name)).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            resultcontactproperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        }
        var dict = resultcontactproperties.ToDictionary(propInfo => propInfo.Name, propInfo => propInfo.Name);
        return dict;
    }  

 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.properties, new SelectList(
 Entity.Data.ContactManager.GetProperties<Contact>(),"Key","Value"), 
 "Select a Property")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...It saved me a day's work..It worked perfectly..And by the way if I need only some of the properties ...how to get them?Is there any solution for that

Comment: Well Mr.Abhijeet can you help me out?

Comment: Answer updated. You can pass in an array of strings for the property names you need. GetProperties<Contact>("FirstName","LastName") If you need all properties just use GetProperties<Contact>(). Hope this helps

Comment: If you know the names of the properties at compile time, why do you need reflection?

Comment: I'm assuming he needs the *property value* and not the name twice, in which case it makes sense.

Comment: I just need the properties of the class ...So by using reflection we can get them right...

Comment: @MattDavey : Agreed, it wouldn't make much sense to use reflection if you knew the property names up front. The only benefit (I can think of) in having the GetProperties method accept the names would be that the experience would be consistent and you'd get back a dictionary regardless of whether the property names were specified or not. Unless the OP provides further insight as to his use case it's hard to judge whether this is the best approach or not. Just my 2 cents...